# How to access grid

Tags: c#, razor, telerik, asp.net-mvc-4

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<Test.Model>()
        .Name("TestGrid")
```

How to access the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This could help](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-mvc/grid/exporting-grid-data-to-excel.aspx). In this solution, you only send the grid's current parameters (pagenumber, filter etc.) to the controller, and get the data from bll, using this parameters.

Anyway, I don't think you can send the whole grid to the controller, unless you serialize the grid object, make a server side representation of it, and let the modelbinder the initialize the object from the incomming parameters. 
Or you can write a custom modelbinder too :)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this helps you:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<Test.Model>()
    .Name("TestGrid")
    .DataBinding(db => db.Ajax()
    .Select("action1", "controller1", new { ld, _fr, gridId = "testGrid"  })
```

your action method will have it automatically:

```
public ActionResult action1(string testid)
{

}
```